# python 3 hashlib.sha256().update(newcontent) seems not to overwrite old content

Tags: python-3.x, string-hashing

When I try to use the hash function, it seems the update method doesn't overwrite the string:

For example, given a string magazine

```
hasher = hashlib.sha256() #set the hasher

hasher.update(magazine.encode('utf-8'))
print( int( hasher.hexdigest(), 16 ) % 10**8)

hasher.update(magazine.encode('utf-8'))
print( int( hasher.hexdigest(), 16 ) % 10**8)
```

will print 
73983538
65808855

```
hasher = hashlib.sha256()
hasher.update(magazine.encode('utf-8'))
print( int( hasher.hexdigest(), 16 ) % 10**8)

hasher = hashlib.sha256() #reset the hasher
hasher.update(magazine.encode('utf-8'))
print( int( hasher.hexdigest(), 16 ) % 10**8)
```

will print
73983538
73983538

What exactly is the update function, and is there a way to reset the string without creating a new hasher?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to create a new hasher? One hasher represents the hash of one "thing", the update method exists, such that you can hash large amounts of data (some amount of bytes per time). I.e. both

```
hasher = hashlib.sha256()
hasher.update(b"foo")
hasher.update(b"bar")
```

and

```
hasher = hashlib.sha256()
hasher.update(b"foobar")
```

lead to the same hash.

There is no way to reset the state of the hash object, as the state isn't even (directly) accessible via Python (as it's written in C).

Comment: Great! Also wondering of the difference between hasher.update(b"foo") and hasher.update("foo)

Comment: You have to hand bytes to the hasher, not strings (because they have an ambiguous representation in bytes). I did that with the `b"...."`-prefix, which makes the strings bytestrings. You did that by using `.encode("utf-8")`, which encodes a string (to bytes) using the UTF-8 encoding.

In Python 2, bytes and strings were the same, and there was a seperate `unicode` type which is what strings are in Python 3.